# R2WinBUGS error (no prior specified for this initial value)

Tags: winbugs, r2winbugs

The original WinBUGS code is as follows:

```
model { for (i in 1:n) {for (j in 1:J) {y[i,j] <- equals(D[i],j)
D[i] ~ dcat(p[i,])
p[i,j]  <- phi[i,j] / sum(phi[i,]) 
LL[i,j] <- y[i,j]*log(p[i,j])}
for (j in 2:J) {                     
S.ed[i,j] <-  c1[j]*ed.c[i]+equals(degree,2)*c2[j]*ed.c[i]*ed.c[i]+inprod(delta.c[j,],Spline[i,])
log(phi[i,j]) <- beta0[j] + beta1[j]*white[i] +  beta2[j]*exp.c[i] + S.ed[i,j]}
LLt[i] <- sum(LL[i,])
phi[i,1] <- 1
H[i] <- 1/exp(LLt[i])
exp.c[i] <- exp[i]-mean(exp[])
ed.c[i] <- ed[i]-mean(ed[])}
# Priors
beta0[1] <- 0; beta1[1] <- 0; beta2[1] <- 0; c1[1] <- 0; c2[1] <- 0
for (j in 2:J) {beta1[j] ~ dnorm(0,0.0001)
beta2[j] ~ dnorm(0,0.0001)
c1[j] ~ dnorm(0,0.0001)
c2[j] ~ dnorm(0,0.0001)
beta0[j] ~ dnorm(0,0.0001)}
Dv <- -2*sum(LLt[])
for (k in 1:K) {knot.c[k] <- knot[k]-mean(ed[])
# degree =1 for linear spline, =2 for quadratic spline 
for (i in 1:337) { S[i,k] <- (ed.c[i]-knot.c[k])*step(ed[i]-knot[k])
Spline[i,k] <- pow(S[i,k],degree)}}
# Random spline coefficients
for (j in 2:J) {for (k in 1:K) {delta[j,k] ~ dnorm(0,tau[j]); delta.c[j,k] <- delta[j,k]-mean(delta[j,])}
# full conditionals for spline precision
tau[j] ~ dgamma(As[j],Bs[j]);     As[j] <- 0.1 + K/2;    Bs[j] <- 0.1 + inprod(delta.c[j,],delta.c[j,])/2}}

*INITIS*

list(beta1=c(NA,0,0,0,0),beta2=c(NA,0,0,0,0),c1=c(NA,0,0,0,0),
c2=c(NA,0,0,0,0),tau=c(NA,1,1,1,1),
beta0=c(NA,0,0,0,0),delta=structure(.Data=c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),.Dim=c(5,6)))

list(beta1=c(NA,-0.5,0.5,0,0),beta2=c(NA,-0.5,0.5,0,0),
c1=c(NA,-0.5,0.5,0,0),c2=c(NA,-0.5,0.5,0,0),tau=c(NA,1,1,1,1),
beta0=c(NA,-0.5,0.5,0,0),delta=structure(.Data=c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,
-0.5,0.5,-0.5,0.5,-0.5,0.5,-0.5,0.5,-0.5,0.5,-0.5,0.5,-0.5,
0.5,-0.5,0.5,-0.5,0.5,-0.5,0.5,-0.5,0.5,0,0),.Dim=c(5,6)))


*DATA*
```

my own R2WinBUGS code is like this.

```
rm(list=ls())
setwd("C:/Users/~~/BMCD")

Data <- read.table("model604data.txt")
D<-Data[,1]; exp<-Data[,2]; ed<-Data[,3]; white<-Data[,4]; J=5; K=6; n=337; knot=c(9.6,12,13.6,14,16,16.4); degree=2;
data <- list(D=D, exp=exp, ed=ed, white=white, J=J, K=K, n=n, knot=knot, degree=degree)

parameters <- c("beta0","beta1","beta2")

inits =list(list(beta1=c(NA,0,0,0,0),beta2=c(NA,0,0,0,0),c1=c(NA,0,0,0,0),c2=c(NA,0,0,0,0),tau=c(NA,1,1,1,1),beta0=c(NA,0,0,0,0),delta=structure(.Data=c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,
                                               0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),.Dim=c(5,6))),
   list(beta1=c(NA,-0.5,0.5,0,0),beta2=c(NA,-0.5,0.5,0,0),c1=c(NA,-0.5,0.5,0,0),c2=c(NA,-0.5,0.5,0,0),tau=c(NA,1,1,1,1),beta0=c(NA,-0.5,0.5,0,0),delta=structure(.Data=c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,
                                                    -0.5,0.5,-0.5,0.5,-0.5,0.5,-0.5,0.5,-0.5,0.5,-0.5,0.5,-0.5,0.5,-0.5,0.5,-0.5,0.5,-0.5,0.5,-0.5,0.5,0,0),.Dim=c(5,6))) )


model604 <- bugs(data, inits, parameters,model.file="C:/Users/~~/model604.odc",
             debug=TRUE,n.chains=2, n.iter=2000, n.burnin=500, bugs.directory="C:/Program Files/WinBUGS14/" )'
```

[image]

How can I fix this error?
I tried to change NA in inits to 0, but it didn't work and give me another error message.
The data follows rectangular format but it's alright
the syntax translation for model and data will be okay, I guess.
Should I add the prior condition?